# Is it possible to define a euclidean structure on infinite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

It is known that for every infinite dimensional vector space $V$, there exists a Hamel basis $B$, such that each $v\in V$ can be repsentated as $$v=\sum_{i=1}^{n(v)}a_ie_i$$ with $e_i \in B$. Now my question is, can we define a euclidean norm on V in the sense of $$\parallel v \parallel=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n(v)}\mid a_i\mid^2 } $$?

Comment: Can you define this norm? Sure (see for example the familiar $\ell^2$ spaces [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#Properties_of_%E2%84%93p_spaces_and_the_space_c0)), but probably you have some idea of what properties you'd like this norm to have.  In particular it will not usually give the same topology as $V$ may have had originally.

Comment: @hardmath would you know whether two choice of Hamel basis result in the same topology?

Comment: @Thomas:  I suspect not.  I think the norms depend on the choice of bases in such a way that a sequence of vectors can converge in one norm and not in another.  But it's a good question.

Comment: @Thomas They may not. Consider (without loss of generality $\dim V=\aleph_0$) $B_1=\{e_i\}_{i\in \Bbb N}$ and $B_2=\{f_i\}_{i\in\Bbb N}$ with $f_n=\sum_{j=1}^n e_j$. Then $\lVert f_n\rVert_1=\sqrt n$ and $\lVert f_n\rVert_2=1$ for all $n$. Therefore $id:(V,\lVert \bullet\rVert_2)\to(V,\lVert \bullet\rVert_1)$ is not continuous because it is (linear and) not bounded on the unit ball.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've indeed described a norm, and it's also induced by a scalar product such that $\langle e_i,e_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$ for all $i,j$ (such a scalar product is unique, given an algebraic basis). This norm is complete if and only if the dimension of the space is finite. This is proved by the fact that if $\{e_{i_1},e_{i_2},e_{i_3},\cdots\}$ is a countable subsequence of $B$, then the sequence of vectors $v_n=2^{-n}e_{i_n}$ satisfies $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \lVert v_j\rVert<\infty$, despite there being no vector $w$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lVert w-\sum_{j=1}^n v_j\right\rVert=0$.

In fact, let there be such $w$ and $w=\sum_{h=1}^m w_he_h+\sum_{j=1}^n w_{i_j}e_{i_j}$ - where $e_1,\cdots,e_m$ are not among the $\{e_{i_1},e_{i_2},\cdots\}$. Then, for all $r\ge n+1$ $$\left\lVert w-\sum_{j=1}^r v_j\right\rVert=\sqrt{\sum_{h=1}^m \lvert w_h\rvert^2+\sum_{j=1}^n \lvert w_{i_j}-2^{-j}\rvert^2+\sum_{j=n+1}^{r}2^{-2j}}\ge 2^{-(n+1)}$$

So the sequence of those quantities can't converge to $0$.

Comment: Thank you. What does it mean for a norm to be complete?

Comment: It mean that the metric $d(x,y)=\lVert x-y\rVert$ is complete, i.e. that all Cauchy sequences converge to some limit.